# .NET Excel data using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, .net, sql, excel

I have an Excel file with a large amount of data which needs to be inserted to MS Sql server table.
The Excel data contains different data types in each column. I need to loop through the data of row each row and convert it to a string where each column for that row is seperated by a comma.

```
Excel data ( | = column seperation):

ID | FirstName | LastName |

1  | John      | Smith    |

2  | Amy       | Jones    |
```

So the new rows will look like:

```
Row 1= ID, FirstName, LastName

Row 2= 1, John, Smith

Row 3= 2, Amy, Jones
```

Then each row of data after the conversion needs to be inserted in to Sql table. Please note the excel file is likely to contain 10,000+ rows.

What is the most efficient way to do this in .NET using C# please?

Comment: Thanks guys.I should state that this needs to be done in .NET because it is a piece of functionality that is to be added to a windows application. I was thinking more to use the OleDbCommand to select the data and then some how loop through the rows and create the data I needed...

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the following C# program:

1. Read Excel file contents using the classes in `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace.
2. Convert the rows and write them in another file in a format that SQL Server's [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command understands.
3. Use the BULK INSERT command to efficiently insert all the rows in SQL Server database.

**UPDATE**: There are also a number of supported methods that **do not require writing any code**. The following knowledge base article summarizes them all: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686.

Comment: Check this example: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: Whether this is the most efficient solution, I'm not sure. Though arguably BULK INSERT is very fast if not the fastest method to insert data in SQL Server.

Comment: aF's solution to use the SqlBulkCopy object in System.Data.SqlClient avoids the use of Excel Interop.  Alternatively, look at ClosedXML (http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) to read in Excel data via the OpenXML interface - again, much better than using Excel Inteorp.

Comment: Thanks guys.I should state that this needs to be done in .NET because it is a piece of functionality that is to be added to a windows application. I was thinking more to use the OleDbCommand to select the data and then some how loop through the rows and create the data I needed...

Comment: @jklemmack: I don't think using SqlBulkCopy object avoids using Excel interop since it has nothing to do with Excel, only SQL Server. Granted there probably are more efficient ways to read the Excel file than Interop but SqlBulkCopy is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to Bulk Insert into SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy.

You have to read as well the excel and create a .csv file but after that all the work is done. You can check [THIS](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=323) example.

Answer (score 0):

Go multithreaded, it's the most efficient way to insert large volumes of data which you need to convert on the fly without using SqlBulkCopy. The reasoning being that while one thread is working on converting its current row data to the format you require the other threads are reading from the data source or inserting in to the database.

I have an Excel spread sheet which is received each month and inserted in to a SQL server database. The sheet contains approximately 260,000 rows and it takes just over 1 minute to insert all the data using the program I wrote. When trying to insert them sequentially the program ran for more than 40 minutes before I killed it.

My solution uses VB.net simply because the Excel interaction is easier. You could write something similar in C# or create a library (DLL) from the VB code and link to it from your C# app. It loads the entire spread sheet in to memory then assigns chunks of 10k rows to separate threads; any remaining rows less than 10k at the end are assigned to the last thread. Each thread reads a row of data from memory, creating an `INSERT` statement and executing it against the database.

I'm happy to share the code if you would like, but it's a bit much to post in this answer. Let me know if you are interested.